# cite paper in sequence

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have the problem that at the beginning of the paper, the cite number start from 9, not the regular 1. How to make the cite number in the main body of paper to be in order in overleaf? I tried to recompile, but it did not work?
example(2 files):

file1:`a.cls`

```
% Bibliography stuff.
% Natbib gives sorting of numeric references.
% We don't use the compress option, because we
% want each reference to have its own popup
\usepackage[sort,numbers]{bmvc2k_natbib}
```

file2:`a.tex`

```
\bibliography{egbib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, can you add your MWE?

Comment: Looks like you use a citing-order for your bibliography. If you want the citations to be numbered in the order you cited them you have to use `,sorting=none` for biblatex as package option. For bibtex the style is `unsrt`. With `natbib` the style is called `unsrtnat`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @skillmon. Followed your suggestion, I added `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` after `\bibliography{egbib}` in `a.tex` file (although I used `natbib` style). It's not work.

After that, I tried to add `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` after `\usepackage[sort,numbers]{bmvc2k_natbib}` in file `a.cls`. It works. So I think it's about the scope.